# Sorted list printing out key and value

Tags: c#, sortedlist

How can I print out the key and the value of an item from a sorted list using bool contains? I only want to print out that one which has the key in match. Thanks in advance!

As you asked I declared the sorted list I have a class in it and an artist for key which is from a textboxt of a gui.

Let us say that

```
   string artsearch = something;
   bool contains = list.ContainsKet(artsearch);    
   SortedList<string, Artist> list = new SortedList<string, Artist>();
    Artist a = new Artist(artist, members, albm1);
        a.Name = artist;
        a.Members = members;
        list.Add(artist, a);

   public class Artist : IComparable
{
    public string name;
    public string members;
    public string album;
    public Guid artistID;
    public LinkListGen<string> albums;

    public Artist()
    {
        artistID = new Guid();
    }

    public Artist(string name, string members, LinkListGen<string> albums)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.members = members;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Albums
    {
        get { return album; }
        set { album = value; }
    }


    public string Members
    {
        get { return members; }
        set { members = value; }
    }



    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Artist)
        {
            Artist other = (Artist)obj;
            return name.CompareTo(other.name);
        }
        if (obj is string)
        {
            string other = (string)obj;
            return members.CompareTo(other);
        }
        else
        {
            return -999;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what does list contain ?

Comment: a list contains only items of type T, where T is either a reference type or value type, not key value pairs like Dictionary does. What's the definition of your type?

Comment: Well it contains a string and a class. I want to compare a string from the gui textfield with the string key and print out the class. Or better will be printed out into a listbox or so.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `list`

Comment: SortedList<string, Artist> list = new SortedList<string, Artist>();

Comment: It could be I guess. Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the value using the indexer:

```
if(contains)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", artsearch, list[artsearch]);
}
```

You can combine these using `TryGetValue`:

```
Artist value;
if(list.TryGetValue(artsearch, out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", artsearch, value);
}
```

Note this works on any class which implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, not just `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Note: That assumes `SortedList` rather than `List`, of course (a reasonable assumption given the OP)

Comment: Well it works. At least sort of for me. The problem is that the value of this is a whole class. An I need to print out all the details of the object, which is the class of course.

Comment: @user3460051 - You could override `ToString` on your `Artist` class, otherwise you will have to manually do the formatting you want.

Comment: Thank you it is a good idea. :-)))) I will try that one.

Comment: I did manage to make it work, but not without your help. Thanks fellows! :-)))